# MySQL Stored Procedure Variables - When to Use Which

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, declare

I am new to MySQL. When do we use declared variable? When to use undeclared variable `(@varTest)`.

I am wondering about the best practice. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's much difference, but you can't declare the type of `@` variables.

Comment: Check: [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and [13.6.4 Variables in Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-variables.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always create procedural variables with `DECLARE` to maintain proper scope. Session variables declared outside the function can be changed inside the function, and vice-versa.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS foo;
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE foo INT;
        SET foo = 123;
        SET @foo = 456;
        SELECT foo, @foo;
    END$

DELIMITER ;

SET @foo = "BAR";
CALL foo();
SELECT @foo;
```

Comment: +1. There are uses for user-defined variables (`@foo`) in MySQL. Use them where you need them, in places a procedure variable isn't valid.  Within a stored program, use procedure variables (`DECLARE foo`) anywhere you have a choice, where either type of variable will work.

Comment: Thank you @miken32 and @spencer7593!